# Azure SQL DB Serverless won't auto pause

Tags: azure-sql-database, serverless

Looking at Query Performance Insight I found this query running 3-4 times/hr (my autopause setting is 1hr):

```
SELECT c.*,
                    i.object_id, i.unique_index_id, i.is_enabled, i.change_tracking_state_desc, i.has_crawl_completed,
                    i.crawl_type_desc, i.crawl_start_date, crawl_end_date,
                    i.incremental_timestamp, i.stoplist_id, i.data_space_id, i.property_list_id,
                    cast(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(i.object_id, 'TableFullTextMergeStatus') as int) as merge_status,
                    cast(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(i.object_id, 'TableFulltextDocsProcessed') as int) as docs_processed,
                    cast(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(i.object_id, 'TableFulltextFailCount') as int) as fail_count,
                    cast(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(i.object_id, 'TableFulltextItemCount') as int) as item_count,
                    cast(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(i.object_id, 'TableFulltextKeyColumn') as int) as key_column,
                    cast(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(i.object_id, 'TableFulltextPendingChanges') as int) as pending_changes,
                    cast(OBJECTPROPERTYEX(i.object_id, 'TableFulltextPopulateStatus') as int) as populate_status
                    FROM [46e881b7-c5f1-41cb-8eee-7c92a89cba41].sys.dm_fts_active_catalogs c
                    JOIN [46e881b7-c5f1-41cb-8eee-7c92a89cba41].sys.fulltext_indexes i on c.catalog_id = i.fulltext_catalog_id
```

Any thoughts on what might be going on? Is there a way to detect the origin of the query? I only have one VM hooked up to the db, and I have services turned off, so not sure what is causing this periodic call.

Comment: When I say services above I mean the only services I know of that know about this database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue using **Query Performance Insight, where I was able to view actual activity including query text.** Even though I had configured the service's own scheduler to make it go to sleep, the service was still querying the DB. Once I actually turned the service off using the Task Scheduler, the DB paused after an hour of inactivity.

**Query Performance Insight is a great tool for determining exactly what is going on with your database**. One thing to remember though, if the database is paused and you navigate to Query Performance Insight, the database will be brought online.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a system query that is fired on Azure SQL Database when your databases use Full-Text indexes. You are seeing this running almost every hour, but you may see it running every 5 minutes sometimes. This is happening since early this year.

Full-text Search is considered an external service on Azure Serverless that explains that query coming regularly to execute on the database. Please read below:

Excerpt: "The resources of a serverless database are encapsulated by app package, SQL instance, and user resource pool entities.

The app package is the outer most resource management boundary for a database, regardless of whether the database is in a serverless or provisioned compute tier. The app package contains the SQL instance and external services that together scope all user and system resources used by a database in SQL Database. Examples of external services include R and full-text search." Source [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview#monitoring).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be completely related to the OP's issue but seems like a good place to add this info as it may be of help to others running into this issue. I recently ran into an issue with Azure not auto-pausing as well. I was struggling to figure out the source of it as all of my connections were closed every evening and I ran a script to kill all active connections from the server side as well. Sometimes 3rd party software can keep the connection alive - in my case Redgate Sql Search tool. After removing the 3rd party tool, it now works as intended again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your low-time is predictable, with just a bit of effort you can setup a schedule with logic apps. E.g. switch to 100 DTUs every morning, and switch back to 10 DTUs every evening.

**It's easy to do and compared to auto-pause it gives you total control.** Lower tiers are almost free so it serves the purpose just as good.

IMO In the long run it's easier to maintain than troubleshooting random wake-up events.